# Calculating the number of missing numbers

Tags: java, android, xml

I am developing an Android Application, which is a numerology app. In which the value of calculating the name is doing:

A, J, S – 1
B, K, T – 2
C, L, U – 3
D, M, V – 4
E, N, W – 5
F, O, X – 6
G, P, Y – 7
H, Q, Z – 8
I, R – 9.

This is the value of each letter. When user enter the name his value is calculated and display the result. I developed the code for calculating the value. But now I need to calculate the missing numbers. For example my name is `ROSHAN` and my value is `R - 9, O - 6, S - 1, H - 8, A - 1, N - 5`. So when I calculate all these values `9+6+1+8+1+5 = 30 = 3+ 0 = 3`. So my value is three. I did the code for that.

I am developing code for the finding the number of missing numbers like in my name missing numbers is 2,3,4,7 so the number of missing numbers in 4. Can anyone help me? I have provided the code I have developed so far.

Mainactivity.java

```
long sum70 = 0;
long sum80 = 0;
long sum90 = 0
sum70 = getsum70(et7.getText().toString());
sum80 = getSum80(et8.getText().toString());
sum90 = getSum90(et9.getText().toString());
private long getsum70(String text) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  long sum70 = 0;
  char[] name70 = new char[text.length()];

  name70 = text.toCharArray();

  for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
  {
    sum70 += value70( name70[i] );
  }

  while (sum70>9 )
  {                  
    sum70 = findDigitSum70(sum70);        
  }
  return sum70;
}


private long value70(char a) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch(a)
  {
  case 'A': 
    return 1;    
  case 'B':
    return 2;
  case 'C':
    return 3;
  case 'D':
    return 4;
  case 'E':
    return 5;
  case 'F':
    return 6;
  case 'G':
    return 7;
  case 'H':
    return 8;
  case 'I':
    return 9;
  case 'J':
    return 1;
  case 'K':
    return 2;
  case 'L':
    return 3;
  case 'M':
    return 4;
  case 'N':
    return 5;
  case 'O':
    return 6;
  case 'P':
    return 7;
  case 'Q':
    return 8;
  case 'R':
    return 9;
  case 'S':
    return 1;          
  case 'T':
    return 2;
  case 'U':
    return 3;
  case 'V':
    return 4;
  case 'W':
    return 5;
  case 'X':
    return 6;
  case 'Y':
    return 7;
  case 'Z':
    return 8;
  default:         
    return 0;

  }
}

private long findDigitSum70(long n) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  int sum70=0;
  while (n != 0) 
  {
    sum70 += n % 10;
    n = n / 10;
  }
  return sum70;
}
```

Comment: Variables names are bad, your code is very hard to understand.

Comment: I've voted to close. It seems to me that you've coded the easy bit, but haven't even made an attempt at the harder part of the problem. Please try something yourself and come to us with a *specific* question about your *attempted solution*. If you edit your question to include your solution, please use consistent indentation of your code (like I've done in my edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use int array, you can solve this problem more easy.

```
int[] points = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

This array's index is each point. 
For example, If you get character 'R', add 1 to points[9].
If you get character 'O', add 1 to points[6].

If you enter your name, the values in array will be like this.

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] - index

{0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1} - value

If value is 0, that value's index will missing number.
And total points will be sum of each [index * value].

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping a switch case, it will be better to store the values of each character in an array of 26 elements.

In that case you can iterate over that array and add the element to either of the two temporary arrays - valuesFoundInNameArray and ValuesNotFoundInTheNameArray